# Mediation call glitch in "Better Call Saul"

Tags: better-call-saul

In *Better Call Saul* season 6, episode 7, as the scam on Howard is about to unfold, Erin Brill asks Miss Falco from Provo to unmute and confirm she’s on the mediation call. Why does Erin do this?

Comment: In your title you call this a "glitch."  Is that because you think it might be a plot or continuity error?  What do you mean by "glitch" here?

Comment: I use that term in the sense of an anomaly in the technology of the phone call, which prompted Erin Brill's concern.

Answer (score 4):

There's an audible indicator that someone joined/left the call. This was triggered when Jimmy and Kim join using the pilfered details Francesca acquired.

Erin, hearing this, was concerned that someone had been disconnected from the call and was checking that all of the class representatives were still present.

Comment: Thanks. This explanation helps.  I wonder if there's a particular reason she mentions the name Falco.  I recall that Falco is the name of the malpractice company's agent with whom Jimmy meets.  From the voice, it's clearly not the same person.  I think the use of the same name may just be a coincidence, but I have found practically no other coincidences on "Saul." Thanks for your comment.  I rewatched 607 and heard the audible indicator you mentioned.

Comment: It may be that was just that was the one person Erin thought most likely to have difficulty with the technology to join the conference call. Or possibly Miss Valco was the one to drop out of a call previously.